# Calculate Percent for funnel

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

How would you present an amount as percentage of total  (I am trying to present funnel data in percentage)? Is this possible in Quicksight?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the percentage of each layer relative to the first layer (total) in a funnel graph you can follow [these instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/new-charts-formatting-and-layout-options-in-amazon-quicksight/).

TLDR:

- Select your funnel graph
- Click the gear icon that appears at the top right of your graph
- On the left panel, select *Data labels*
- Under *Metric label style*, choose *Value and percent of first*